# If $f$ is analytic in a punctured disk and $f'$ is bounded then is $f$ bounded

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a slight problem. If $f$ is analytic in a punctured disk and $f'$ is bounded in the punctured disks then can we say that $f$ bounded in that disk? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes -- as the antiderivative of a bounded function on a set were every two points are connected by a path of bounded length, $f$ has to be bounded itself.

It doesn't matter for this that the domain is specifically a punctured disk -- but just for completeness, notice that if $f'$ is bounded in the punctured disk (and is analytic because that's what complex derivatives on an open set are), then the singularity of $f'$ at the puncture must be *removable*. Remove it, and we see that $f$ itself must have a removable singularity there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am still wondering how I can show that if f' has a removable singularity f also does too

Comment: @Heisenberg: One way is to show that $f$ is bounded in the vicinity of the singularity (which is what you have just done). Another one is to fill in the missing value for $f'$ and take an antiderivative of the completed $f'$ it that agrees with $f$ at some point. Then the antiderivative has to agree with $f$ everywhere in the punctured disk, so it directly shows how to extend $f$ to fill the puncture.

Comment: I agree with Henninh Makholm, but I think it is not necessary to remove singularities. Let $|f'(x)|\leq M$. Assuming that $f$ is unbounded, there are  two points $z,w$ in the punctured disk such that $|f(z)-f(w)|>3M$. But since $z$ and $w$ are connected by a path of length $2+\varepsilon$, at most, this gives a contradiction.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I agree that it is not necessary to remove the singularity. That's why I wrote "it doesn't matter for this ...". The argument you sketch is essentially the same as I had in mind for the first paragraph of the answer. (Except that the problem doesn't say that the punctured disk is a _unit_ disk).